# Custom Layout for Client

Tags: identityserver4

I've installed an Identity Server 4 server with the ASP.NET Identity bits enabled.

When the user is redirected over to the Identity Server's log in page (which is now the ASP.NET Identity login page) is there a way to determine which *Client* the user has come from?

My particular use-case is to enabling some customization of the login page (a different MVC layout) for different clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our sample UI shows how to do that -

- inject `IIdentityServerInteractionService` into the account controller
- call the `GetAuthorizationContext` method to get information like e.g. the client id.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs

Comment: Thanks for the link, I never thought of looking in the Quickstart samples.